Family member to EU citizen exempt from 90/180 days Schengen rule
I know there are many similar questions on this topic just today I've cme to a valid answer by a border control officer thus I wanted also to confirm this with the rest of the members (who have experienced a similar situation).
I'm a third country national married to a EU national and I've entered the Schengen without my husband i.e. I've joined him in his country of residence (France). Now according the Schengen calculator I've stayed 80 days of 90 in the period of 180 days. According the to EU directive of Free movement I'm exempt of the Schengen rule as stipulated in the law:
"If your non-EU family members have the required documents, they are entitled to accompany or join you without any conditions or formalities for consecutive periods of up to 3 months per EU country visited. They are not subject to the overall limitation of up to 90 days in a 180-day period that applies in the Schengen area. You can combine stays in different EU countries without an overall time-limit (as long as the conditions of the EU rules on residence are met)."
Today I have also visited a border police to clarify this and they confirmed me that in the Schengen the family members of the EU citizens are exempt from the Schengen rule, as long they stay 3 months per country, after which they need to apply for a residence permit.
For me the question is: How we prove that I have stayed for eg. 2 months in Italy, and after 1 month in Germany etc. since there is no formal registration when traveling within the Schengen area?, we are not obligated to declare presence up to 3 months! This is very confusing because the proof of staying in each of the Schengen countries will serve as a justification that I haven't overstayed more than 3 months per country. Does anyone have any similar experience or know something about this? How we justify stay in each country, since we don't have an address yet, we are traveling.

Related questions: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64168/long-stay-schengen-visa-requirement-for-spouse-of-uk-citizen https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103571/non-eu-wife-staying-more-than-90-days-in-eu https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129093/croatian-citizen-traveling-thru-schengen-with-non-croatian-spouse


For me the Question is: How we proof that I have stayed for eg. 2 months in Italy, and after 1 month in Germany etc. since there is no formal registration when traveling within the Schengen?

You don't need to. One way to understand why is to remember that you are also allowed to stay longer than 3 months in any given EU country. The only difference is that you are then required to complete some formalities and would be issued a residence card.
If you don't apply for the residence card in time, you may risk a fine but nothing more. You don't need a permission to reside in the EU and your right to stay is not contingent on completing these formalities.

This is very confusing because the proof of staying in each of the Schengen countries will serve as a justification that I haven't overstayed more than 3 months per country.

Border guards at external borders are not in charge of enforcing this and in practice, they won't care but if they really wanted to push it, only the country where you stayed longer than 3 months would have some basis to impose a fine. In that case, it's up to them to prove you broke the rules, you don't have to prove anything. That's completely different from the rules on the length of stay that apply to people who are not covered by the EU freedom of movement where the burden of proof is on the visitor and a lack of stamp is enough to impose a penalty.

Thank you so much for your reply and for providing me so useful information, I appreciate a lot. Yes I'm aware that I can apply for a residence once I've passed the period of 3 months in some country..But again, how would they know whether I'm for eg. in Germany 3 or 4 months before applying? How do I proof this? Also I've arrived in the Schengen 80days back where I've joined my husband, now we plan to travel in Germany, so according my stamps in the passport I'll be overstaying, but how do I proof that all this time I'm traveling with my husband? Thank you enormously for your support!

@user163594 What I am trying to explain is that you would NOT be overstaying as you have a right to stay for longer than 3 months. At most, you would be violating this obligation to register, that's completely different. That's why you don't really have to prove anything as long as you are crossing the border with your husband.

Now if you do want to settle in Germany and you are concerned about the way the registration works and what happens if you do that too late, I would recommend asking a question specifically about that on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Thank you again for being so supportive, you are helping me so much by clarifying this exemption of the Schengen rule..I don't want to sound like I'm exaggerating, but I wanted to make sure that all is good if I remain in the Schengen..Thank you again for assuring me it means a lot me !!

@user163594 Again, if you are genuinely traveling to several countries with your husband, you have no reasons to be concerned. On the other hand, if you are crossing the border without him and actually residing in France then you should really get a residence card. It will also make things much easier. Either way, you don't need to worry too much about the exact number of days or how to prove anything.

If you’re really worried about it, keep some form of evidence of each trip eg flight tickets, hotel reservation, even restaurant/shop purchases. It might be worth the (relatively) small amount of hassle to do this, for peace of mind. But as the other comments say, you don’t need to worry really.

@user163594 "But again, how would they know whether I'm for eg. in Germany 3 or 4 months before applying?" Most likely, they'll ask for the date of your arrival in Germany and not seek further proof.  If they do, any evidence wil likely be sufficient; what's clear is that the evidence won't be in your passport since as you note internal border crossings aren't tracked.

@Relaxed Thank you again for providing me so many information..yes for now we intend to travel and maybe potentially settle in Germany, but this is not confirmed yet..To be honest I haven't applied for a residency in FR because the administration is exceptionally slow, it takes a lot of time and nerves..For now, as I've understood, I'm protected by the EU law as long as I travel with my husband..trying to exiting/entering  the schengen alone I might be faced with a fine..Thank you for clarifying all of this, it means so much to me

@Traveller Thank you so much..Yes, that is a good idea, keeping receipts of various places, that should be enough for proving a presence in a country (at least is something). Thank you a lot

@phoog Thank you a lot..Yes indeed there is no way they can know when I've entered..I was yesterday at the german border police to get some information, I've asked what is my duty i.e. when I'll arrive in Germany, when and where to register my entrance in country.?.They replied to me that I don't need to register, only if after 3 months I decide to apply for a residency permit in this case a registration of presence is required..That is kind of gap, because again, for eg. whenever I decide to apply for a residency for eg. they would not really know how long I was in in the country..
